Can I adjust the height of my custom iOS share extension UI?
I am working on a share extension for my app, but I cannot figure out how to limit the height of the UI for the extension. The problem is that if I present (modally) another view on top of this one, this too-tall UI goes behind the "Dynamic Island". While not a dealbreaker, I know it's possible to do this, since it can be seen in the comparison below, and I would like for my app to always respect the safe areas. I also do not want to use storyboards.
A simple version of my UI. Note the closeness to the island at the top

Here is an example of the iMessage share extension UI and the distance from the top that I want to achieve

Here is the simplified code that I used to produce the first image:
import UIKit
import Social

class ShareViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        let title = UILabel()
        title
            .text = "Share Extension"
        view.addSubview(title)
        title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 30),
            title.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

I've tried things like setting preferredContentSize, but what has gotten me closest is adjusting the NSLayoutContraints, but it's incredibly finicky and doesn't seem to behave the way I expect so I don't think this is the right approach, but I may be wrong. Usually the view doesn't render at all.
Please let me know if there is a way to increase the distance between the top of the safe area and the top of my view.

Present your vc overcurrent context then make original vc view color clear you'll get empty vc then add you custom bottomSheet or view then apply constraints regarding safeArea.top + YOUR_VALUE thats it.
